# Extract 6TB Data from DB2 and Importing in Mangodb

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I want to export large volume of data from DB2 (including BLOB) and want to insert to insert in Mangodb.

Which tool is the best to extract large volume of data from db2.

Thank you in advance!
Bharathi

Answer (score 1):

The best summary of your options is in the **Data Movement Utilities Guide and Reference** manual for your specific DB2 server (ask your DBA if you don't know which platform and version you're running).

Aside from plain old `SELECT` statements, your DB2 database may also support the `EXPORT` utility, which provides a lot of options for delimiting, encoding, and formatting the output. `EXPORT` is not part of SQL, but a server-side export can be initiated from SQL by passing the command into the `ADMIN_CMD` stored procedure. Exporting data directly to a remote DB2 client can be done via DB2's original CLP command line processor (the `db2` shell command) or CLPPlus, which works a lot like SQL*Plus from Oracle.

The fastest option is IBM's **High Performance Unload**, which must be licensed for your DB2 server. Unlike the other options, HPU can also extract data from backup images.